# Can I remove the "nonetheless" in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

When I search the term `jamais vu`, I got a quote:

> In psychology, jamais vu (/ˈʒɑːmeɪ ˈvuː/; from French, meaning "never seen") is the phenomenon of experiencing a situation that one recognizes in some fashion, but that nonetheless seems very unfamiliar.

I'd like to know whether I can remove the word `nonetheless`? What does it do in this sentence?

Comment: It shows a contrast to what has been said before; *but that nonetheless* is more emphatic. I'd just use *... but that seems ...*

Comment: There are many words with a discursive function, such as _nonetheless_, _however_, _just_ that (at least in some cases) add nothing to the literal meaning of a sentence and could be removed, but which convey something about the discourse structure, or the speaker's attitudes.

Comment: Here, you can replace “but that nonetheless” with, “*but despite that*” You can leave it out but it becomes a slightly different sentence than the author’s original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original quote (here with my emphasis):

> In psychology, jamais vu (/ˈʒɑːmeɪ ˈvuː/; from French, meaning "never
>   seen") is the phenomenon of experiencing a situation that *one
>   recognizes in some fashion*, but that nonetheless *seems very
>   unfamiliar*.

**nonetheless** explicitly sets two roughly opposite ideas against one another:

**one recognizes in some fashion ... seems very unfamiliar**

If you leave out **nonetheless**, you are lessening the speaker's *explicit* acknowledgement of their oppositeness.

Consider:

```
1. I have drunk a glass of water. I feel thirsty.

2. I have drunk a glass of water but I feel thirsty.

3. I have drunk a glass of water. Nonetheless I feel thirsty.

4. I have drunk a glass of water but nonetheless I feel thirsty.
```

In #1, there is no explicit connection of the two stated facts.

In #2, **but** explicitly connects the two stated facts.

In #3, **nonetheless** explicitly connects the two stated facts.

In #4, **but** explicitly connects the two stated facts and **nonetheless** *reinforces* the explicit connection.

**nonetheless** can be moved to the end of the sentence, punctuating the idea:

**I have drunk a glass of water but  I feel thirsty nonetheless.**

**Nonetheless** means "not any less (here, thirsty) [for having done so]"

We can also use the word "still", which means "continue to".

**I have drunk a glass of water but I *still feel* thirsty.**

I have drunk a glass of water but I *continue to feel* thirsty.